# Indexing/splitting ['ABC:2', 'CDE:3']

Tags: python

I am trying to split up a list such as in the title:

```
['ABC:2', 'CDE:1']
```

Ultimately, I would like to assign the bit before and after the `:` to two different variables as I perform an iteration.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Do you have any control over the format? if the format was slightly different, you could just use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> L = ['ABC:2', 'CDE:1']
>>> for i, j in (x.split(":") for x in L):
...     print i, j
... 
ABC 2
CDE 1
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, thanks so much. only been doing python at uni for 3 months, havent come across that format before. is that list comprehension? whatever it is ill read up on it!

Comment: @user1710566, it's called a generator expression. The syntax works similar to a list comprehension, but it yields the results one at a time, so uses less memory than creating a temporary list

Answer (score 0):

Using higher order functions (which I feel more comfortable with):

```
>>> xs = ['ABC:2', 'CDE:1']
>>> split_xs = map(lambda s : s.split(":"), xs)
>>> for x, y in split_xs:
...   print(x, y)
... 
ABC 2
CDE 1
```

Comment: Then surely, one should use `map(operator.methodcaller('split', ':'), xs)` ?

Comment: @JonClements, that's both longer and stringier. Latter bothers me more.